# OIDC : url differences in code flow and implicit flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, implicit-flow

I am new to `OIDC`. I am referring to [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996OiexHze0&t=1619s)  to use `OIDC` into my application.

Looking at the URL's for Code flow (Response type: Code) and Implicit flow (Response type: Id_token) I have noticed something strange, in redirect URL  `code` is provided as a `query parameter` (followed by `?`) but `id_token` is followed by `#`.   And the same thing is happening in my application also.  Why `id_token` also not provided as a `query parameter`. I have googled but did not find any answer.

code flow url:

[image: code flow]

implicit flow url:

[image: implicit flow]

(video ref: 39:03 , 53:35)

Answer (score 1):

Implicit flow is deprecated and returns tokens directly to the browser. It does so on a (client side) hash fragment which web servers do not include in their log files.

This used to be the solution back when Single Page Apps were new and Authorization Servers did not support CORS.

These days Authorization Code Flow is standard and I would focus all your efforts on that. In this model an Authorization Code is returned in a query parameter but:

- It is one time use, so even if included in server logs it can not usually be exploited
- It typically also requires a client secret in order to exchange it for tokens

These days the Code Flow should also use [PKCE](https://curity.io/resources/learn/oauth-pkce/), which can be used in conjunction with a client secret.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the authorization code flow uses `?code=...` is because this code is intended for the *server*, which receives the query. On the contrary, the implicit flow uses `#id_token=...` because this is intended for the *client*. Browsers only send the URL without the fragment part after the hash to the server.

While the implicit flow regarding the (access) `token` has been deprecated in OAuth2.1, the implicit flow regarding the `id_token` has not.

That said, it is best practice to use the auth code flow over the implicit one to avoid the token to appear in URLs.